# gmap3 DOM button not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dom, jquery-gmap3

[image]

Here's the UI i'm working with. Enter an address, click "See On Map" and a marker appears. If you click on the marker then, "Add Member Details" button appears.

I need it so that when the user clicks the "Add Member Details" button, a modal form will appear. Right now, it doesn't work. I recieve no errors. Its just a blank button. I've tried to initiate an alert and still got nothing.

I've already tested to see if my modal works when initiated by another button and it works great - I think my issue is because the "Add Member Details" button is a DOM generated button. Can anyone help?

Using Twitter Bootstrap (3.0), gMap 3.0, BootBox.js, and  jQuery 1.10

```
 $('.init_form').click(function(e){
    $('#dialog-demo-1').modal();
    e.preventDefault();
 });


function seeOnMap(xaddress) {
        $('#gmap-4').gmap3({
              marker:{
                address: xaddress, id:'newuser_marker', data:"<div><button type='button' class='btn btn-success init_form'  id='newmember_form'>Add Member Details</button></div>",
                events:{ 
                     click: function(overlay, event, context){
                        var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                            infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
                        if (infowindow){
                            infowindow.open(map, overlay);
                            infowindow.setContent(context.data);
                        } else {
                            $(this).gmap3({
                            infowindow:{
                            anchor:overlay, 
                            options:{content: context.data}
                       }
                   });
               }
           },
                }
              },
                         map:{
                options:{
                  center: [xx.xxxxxx,xx.xxxxxx],
                  zoom: 11
                }
              }
        });
    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="dialog-demo-1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Signup form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Name</label>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" />    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok I finally figured it out:

should be:

```
  $(document).on('click','.init_form',function(e){
      $('#dialog-demo-1').modal();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```